# Visual Studio: Testing a WebAPI using from external physical devices (Not localhost)

Tags: visual-studio-2015, localhost

My WebAPI works when hosted on localhost, as long as the Web Client is also on the same PC.  My issue is I now need to test + debug the WebAPI using remote client devices.

How can I setup Visual Studio 2015 Options.Web.ProjectUrl (or other setting hosts file) to expose the WebAPI using the IPv4 address of the VS2015 PC hosting the WebAPI?

I have a few different embedded devices that I need to test with the WebAPI - on the same subnet.

I'd like the Web API client to access the VS2015 PC (WebAPI ) using a url of the form: url:192.168.10.XX\webAPI\   instead of url: 127.0.0.1\WebAPI\

Thanks in Adv.

Comment: share your code which you have write and also show error which you have get and need to refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

I found a Visual Studio Extension Conveyor by Keyoti that does exactly what I need and also allows you to access your Web API / Web APPL over the internet

https://keyoti.com/products/conveyor/index.html

But happy for comments if someone finds a cleaner way to achieve this in VS2015